# C++ Precedence via filing

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I want to solve this type of expressions after reading from filing with precedence

**2+3/5*9+3-4**

Here is my code for attempt to solve that task how can i solve this problem

```
while ( !inputFile.eof() ) {
  getline( inputFile, read );
  cout << read << endl;
  for ( int i = 0; i < read.length(); i++ ) {
    if ( read[i] == '/' ) {
      result = static_cast<float>(read[i - 1]) / static_cast<float>(read[i + 1]);
      read[i - 1] = result;
      for ( int j = i; j < read.length() - 2; j++ ) {
        read[j] = read[j + 2];
      }
      read[read.length() - 1] = '\0';
      read[read.length() - 2] = '\0';
    }
  }
  cout << result << endl;
  cout << read << endl;
}
```

Comment: You're evaluating the operands as floats but then you store it back into the string as a char, losing any precision. You're evaluating the operands based on their ascii representation and not the actual value. This code assume each operand is only one character long. You only show the division, but when implementing multiplication you'll likely get values larger than 9 and will therefore have issues. I think you should rethink your solution and I advise not trying to do it all in one string.

Comment: I am not sure that I understand what you are trying to do. Evaluating expressions is not a trivial task. [This](http://www.stroustrup.com/3rd_code.html) might help you (look for Desk Calculator).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to build a tree-like structure from your input. First of all you need to lex(/tokenize) your equation so you get a List/Array/whatever container you think fits of your tokens (which are numbers, operators, parenthesis). These may already hold the right datatypes (float or int for numbers and so on).

You may then parse your tokens into a tree-like structure using the right precedence. This the tricky part on building a calculator-like application.

Basically your parsing a grammar here, but you should think about this yourself (it's a good practice).

Your tree structure for **2+3/5*9+3-4** needs to look like this:

```
MINUS
|- PLUS
|  |- PLUS
|  |  |- 2
|  |  |- MULTIPLY
|  |  |  |- DIVIDE
|  |  |  |  |- 3
|  |  |  |  |- 5
|  |  |  |- 9
|  |- 3
|- 4
```

Answer (score 1):

your code has a number of problems

1. there is an index-out-of-bounds error hidden there, in the first iteration of the loop you try to access read[-1] memory address which presumably does not exist
2. read is (presumably) an array of chars, that means that read[i] contains a ASCII character and not a raw number. So, if read[i] contains '5', the result of applying static_cast<float>(read[i]) is '53.0', because ASCII's code for '5' is 53. So what you really need is static_cast<float>(read[i] - '0')
3. you should not store the result of floating point division back into read[i-1], because clearly you are mixing up a floating point value with chars. If you are serious about doing it, you should convert into a string the result of your operation, but I would dare say that's an unnecessary complexity: why don't you simply use a floating point temporary variable to store partial results?
4. there's absolutely no necessity of shrinking the read buffer content after you consume the first two operands, just advance the pointers.

Comment: #1 can only happen if `'/'` is the first character of string, which if given well-formed input won't happen

Comment: I wouldn't assume that the input is well-formed as it isn't checked anywhere.